# Can you stop the jQuery focusout from firing when losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got an input box that I want to have save its value when it loses focus.

Pretty straightforward stuff and I'm able to get that done via jQuery's `focusout` event.

The problem however, is that I want to NOT fire the `focusout` event when the user clicks on an "X" icon next to the input box (example shown below)

[image]

So when the user tabs out of this input box, or clicks outside of the box or they click the green checkbox it should fire the `focusout` event... but if they click the red "X", it should NOT fire the `focusout`.

Is this possible to do with JavaScript / jQuery?

EDIT:

Some of you have recommended using `event.relatedTarget`, but it seems like that's returning null. I'll include my code in question for clarity:

```js
  // This is the cancel button with the red X
  $("body").on("click", "span[id*='Cancel']", function(e)
  {
    showLabel($(this));
  });

  // this is the code to trigger the blur / focusout event
  // trouble is that the "e.relatedTarget" is null
  $("body").on("focusout", "input, textarea", function (e) {
    if($(e.relatedTarget).is("span[id*='Cancel']")){
      return false;
    }

    $(this).siblings("span[id*='OK']").trigger("click");
    return false;
  });
```

Here's a screen grab of me debugging this in JS (you'll see that the `$(e.relatedTarget)` selector returns nothing):

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you want the focusout event on the red "X" button to do nothing? You probably want to rephrase your problem description with some html snippets.

Comment: I have had to do a similar type of thing with a blur event. Basically what I had to do was call a setTimeout on the blur to execute my function to save the data, and then on the click event of the X, cancel the timeout. That way, unless the X is clicked, the save function will fire. The delay can be pretty negligable, too. I think I used something like 50 or 100ms

Comment: You would think that you could use the event variable to determine what caused the event and if the event was triggered by clicking on that button specifically you could add logic to say, if it is this event item, return false, otherwise return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel de event returning the focus to previous element.

```
$('#inputText').focusout(function(event) {
  setTimeout(function(){
       if (document.activeElement.id == "btnCancel") {
            $(event.target).focus();
            return false;
       } 
    },1);
});
```

This jsFiddle shows how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/mpervh3t/

Hope it helps

Comment: FYI 4ms is the minimum delay on setTimeout(). The browser will force it, but I say that relying on the browser to correct your invalid code is not the best future-proof solution

Comment: I'm not sure I like this solution, If there's no other options then I'll likely be stuck with using it, but it feels a bit "hacky"

Comment: Well, if want to cancel the focusout or blur event if you click some specific button, you must check out activeElement to be sure if this element fired the event. You can change the code to be less "hacky", but the idea will be the same :)

Comment: @mhodges, 4 miliseconds is browser implementation, and old IE had like 15 and more. I think there is nothing wrong with using 1 or even 0. Up to some values this works similarily to `setImmediate()` (or at least how is suppose to be working), just pushing it to be done after current stuff is finished.

Comment: @Seb 4ms is the safe value as per the HTML 5 specification, it is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward. In fact, after 5 nested timeouts, it actually forces the value to a minimum of 4ms. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: @mhodges, but how 0ms is unsafe? In both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` time you pass as second argument is more like: do this not before given time. So `setTimeout` 1000 doesn’t mean that it will be fired 1000 miliseconds later but at least. (I know you probably know this but for the sake of other readers.) So I say, “At least 0ms,” and browser replies, “In my case it’ll be 4ms.” Anytime in the future browsers might start firing at 0ms. As long as someone knows how it works, it should be okay. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Seb Agreed, that is a correct interpretation of the delay functionality. I guess my whole thing would be future-proofing the code. What happens if a future browser decides that 0 is no longer a valid value (as has happened with a few different things over the years), your code is unusable. It also creates inconsistency between different browsers because you are heavily relying on someone else to tell you how your code works, and that may change at any given point in time. I mention 4ms because it is the safest, most consistent value across all browser implementations right now.

Comment: @Seb As far as HTML5 browsers go, testing shows that 4ms is 4ms is 4ms. However, 0ms may be 1ms, 2ms, 3ms.. who knows? In my opinion, it is good practice to leave those types of things out of your code whenever possible. Especially in this case because 0 is such a special number in many instances. What is 0ms? Does 0ms even exist, logically? Should it exist? Should we support it? The ambiguity is unnerving

Answer (score 2):

You must use `relatedTarget` like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn").on("focusout",function(e){

        if($(e.relatedTarget).hasClass("red")) {
             alert("You clicked on X button");
        }

        else {

            alert("Fire Focus out")
        }

    })
   })
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .gr {
                color: green;
            }
            .red {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input type="text" class="btn"><button class="gr">Ok</button><button class="red">X</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".btn").on("focusout",function(e){

            if($(e.relatedTarget).hasClass("red")) {
                 alert("You clicked on X button");
            }

            else {

                alert("Fire Focus out")
            }

        })
    })
    </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this code and saw that the relatedTarget for the input button I clicked is an empty object... perhaps because the input box is an input box and the button I'm clicking on is a span (like bootstrap uses)

Comment: The code ehsan has posted works.  It follows the same concept as what I had posted.  But just uses hasClass instead of .is(). 

Take a look at the updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kowmLf2a/2/

Comment: I tried this, and had the same issue as well... the `$(e.relatedTarget)` selector doesn't return anything at all, and the `e.relatedTarget` is `null`

Comment: e.relatedTarget.tagName return tag name.

Comment: @ehsan again, `e.relatedTarget` is `null`, so `e.relatedTarget.tagName` is also `null`

Comment: @Trevor - what is `e`?

Comment: @Adjit `e` is just a shorter variable name for `event`... it's the event handler that's passed into the function

Comment: @Trevor I know... I'm saying what does the object look like. If you do a `console.log(e)` then maybe you can find the property you are looking for or at least understand why `e.relatedTarget` is `null`

Comment: If that's the case then this means that whatever is triggering the event is not the target button that we want.  As if it is blurring before clicking on the button.  Thus would return null.  ( If you watch the event when tabbing out, it returns null as well ), so for some reason, within the flow your binding is being removed before clicking on the target button.

Comment: Wonder if this is browser related.  What browser are you in?

Comment: @AndrewIce I'm using Chrome, and it is absolutely firing the blur event before the button click event. I think for now I'm going to go with the setTimeout hack, as it'll get the job done... but I would still love to find a more elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: I absolutely agree.  In some scenarios.  A hack will have to do until the problem is solved.  But it's never good practice to leave it in the long run.  Especially setTimeout.  I wish I could replicate the problem you're having.  I'll keep playing with it to see what could be going wrong.  Hope you have a great day and keep us updated!

The only sub-solution that's come to mind so far is to set those bindings on input-focus, and if the button is clicked, that function will trigger within the focus, and you could prevent bubbling up to blur event.

Comment: Along with what Adjit said, console.log(e) and look at the info it provides and at the relatedTarget and see why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment:

> "I have had to do a similar type of thing with a blur event. Basically what I had to do was call a setTimeout on the blur to execute my function to save the data, and then on the click event of the X, cancel the timeout. That way, unless the X is clicked, the save function will fire. The delay can be pretty negligable, too."

I found the relevant code

```
var sliderTimeout = null;
$(".slider-trigger").on("blur", function () {
      sliderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
          $(".slider").hide();
      }, 100);
  });

$(".ui-slider-handle").on("focus", function () {
      clearTimeout(sliderTimeout);
});
```

Here is the [full demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldB5E2IoS92ySkLoIKIk?p=preview) of the code in action. It does much more than demonstrate this, but if you examine the behavior of focusing/blur on the "margin" input, you will see that if you blur the margin input, the slider hides, but if you click on the slider, it cancels the hide and stays shown. It's the exact same concept, just a slightly different application.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I did the thing.

https://jsfiddle.net/kowmLf2a/1/

In the blur event I target the related target.  See if that related target is the item that I don't want to blur with.  If it is then return false.

Code for reference:

```
$('#input').blur(function(event){
  if($(event.relatedTarget).is('#bt2')){
    return false;
  }

  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I tried that out but I'm not able get anything from the e.relatedTarget code... the selector has nothing inside of it, so performing a ".is()" check results in false. I've updated my question with the actual code I'm using... perhaps there are some hints in there as to what's going wrong

Comment: Sorry to see that it didn't work.  Let me  look back at my fiddle alongside your code to see if I can find the problem.