# Is there any way to avoid a focusout event when the user switches to an entirely different window?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm currently using

```
$('#input').blur(function(){...
```

in order to handle the loss of focus on an input in my web application.

It behaves as intended for the most part, except I don't want the event to trigger when the user switches to a different window entirely. I noticed that the blur event is triggered even when I switch to my chrome dev tools. This behavior is unintended. I should also mention that using a focusout event produces the same results.

As an example of what I want, you'll notice that if you search for things on google, there appears to be a focusout event when you click away from the input which makes the suggested searches disappear.
However if you click on an entirely different window that isn't your browser, the results will remain on the screen as if the focusout had not been triggered. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214187/11700321

Comment: No, I don't think so. I want to avoid firing the focusout when you click something other than your browser, not if you click a specific element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the input's blur is one of the first to trigger, before even the window's one or any visibilitychange event fires.

This means that we need to delay all executions of this input's event in order to be sure that it wasn't cause by the window's blur. To do so, just store a timeout id that you will cancel in window's blur event handler.

```js
let blur_timeout;
window.addEventListener( 'blur', (e) => {
  clearTimeout( blur_timeout ); // cancel the input's timer
} );
document.getElementById( 'inp' ).addEventListener( 'blur', (e) => {
  // wait a bit so we are sure it's not caused by window's blur
  blur_timeout = setTimeout( handleInputBlur, 10 );
} );

function handleInputBlur() {
  console.log( 'input blurred' );
}
```

```html
<input id="inp">
```

Comment: Is setting a timer the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well.. the only I can think of right now at least. Are you in a case where it's not posible?

Comment: I can do it if it's the only way. It just seems like it's a janky solution. I tried something similar with a different issue I had and I found that even with a 300 ms delay, sometimes the delayed function would fire first somehow.

Comment: 300ms? I made it 10 to be safe, but from my tests even 0 works... ANd I think I remember that per specs, even though the element's event should fire before the viewport's one, all these should happen continuously.  Are you sure there wasn't something else going on when you experienced this issue?

Comment: Let me try it again and see if it's consistent. It very well could have been some other issue. Does the 10ms delay consistently produce the result that you want on your end?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to handle this would be to do the blur action, and undo it if the very next event is `visibilitychange`.

Comment: Yes for me 10ms is always ok, but it's not like I made very extensive tests either, so let us know if you can reproduce your issue in a consistent mean. @Brad visibilitychange will actually fire **after** the page has been blurred, so in a threshold context. window.blur is more reliable here. And not knowing what OP is doing in this event handler, we can't be sure it's even possible to *undo* it (e.g they could send a beacon to server-side or something alike), so to wait before executing seems like the most general solution to me.

Comment: @Brad Some data gets deleted on focusout so undoing the action would be a little bit problematic.

Comment: @Kaiido It works like a charm! Thanks for the great suggestion.